# Share-to-Teams from personal app/tab not working on mobile

Tags: microsoft-teams

We are developing a thrid-party app for Teams.

We are hoping to use the Share-to-Teams function as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/share-to-teams-from-personal-app-or-tab

However this is not working on the mobile client, and we can't get a handle on what is going wrong and the documentation is a bit light.

This is currently only available in developer preview (although I have been informed that it is currently being rolled out), does anyone know if this function is supported on mobile?

Comment: Could you please check which response code you are getting. If it is 100 then it's not supported on mobile platform.

Comment: Did you checked the response code?

Comment: Apologies @Nivedipa-MSFT I have been unable to get the remote debugging working on my Android device, so I have been unable to get an answer to that question.
I will take another look into my debugging problems shortly and will try to get a response back.

Comment: Have you checked this?